# Find the basis for eigenvalues complex numbers

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My Matrix A which acts on $\Bbb{C}^2$:

> $$\begin{vmatrix}
> 0&1\\
> -18&6
> \end{vmatrix}$$

I worked out my eigenvalues: $3 + 3.i, 3-3.i$

Now I need to find the basis for the eigenspace: $3+3.i$

Working out $A-(3+3.i).I$, I get the following two equations (Note I havn't reduced):
$$(-3-3.i)x_1+x_2=0$$
$$-18x_1 + (3-3.i)x_2=0$$
By substituting the one equation into the other I get no where, any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Multiply the first equation by $-3+3i$. You will then get the second, apart from a negative. Your equations are indeed dependent...

Comment: This shouldn't surprise you. You have a system of equations and you want infinitely many solutions (an eigenvector and all its multiples). Hence you need a free variable in this sytem of equations, that's why plugging the equations in each other is useless.

Comment: @Mathematician42 You're right but now how do I tackle it, my goal is to get the eigenvector?

Comment: Well, once you have established that the two equations are dependent (one should always check that to imply no mistakes), then you can pick for $x$ say $t$ and plug that in one of the two equations and obtain an expression for $y$ in terms of $t$. Then you have an eigenvalue. You can then pick for $t$ anything you want (make sure you don't get the zero vector)

Comment: The eigenvectors form (at least) a line, so there is always some ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @imranfat's comment, it is not difficult to see that the first column in
$A-(3+3i)I$ is $-3-3i$ multiple of the second column. So
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\3+3i
\end{pmatrix}$$
is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $3+3i.$